# Extracting from a vector the highest value of a subset of this values given by their location

Tags: r

I have a vector of values and a vector of selected locations in vector A named B

```
A<-c(0.17258359,  0.31238791,  0.08807850,  0.12379649,  0.14670116,  0.13836463, 0.16177369,-0.01230468,  0.12038019,  0.34554023,  0.03835980,  0.10349991, 0.17258359,  ,  0.23248873,  0.17567757,  0.13933847,  0.33572602, 0.15841040,  0.22332176)

B<-c(2,  7,  8, 11, 14)
```

I would like to extract only the LOCATION correponding to the highest value from A which corresponds with the locations given in B. 0.33485513

I have tried with

```
max(which(B == A)) # yields and error     
    [1] -Inf
Mensajes de aviso perdidos
In max(which(B == A)) : ningun argumento finito para max; retornando -Inf
```

EDIT

So it selects value from A of 0.33485513 with location in A given in B 14

Comment: It's unclear to me what are you asking. You already have the locations vector. What do you mean by *"the LOCATION corresponding to the highest value from A which corresponds with the locations given in B"*? Every location in `A` is unique... I would think you need something like `A[B]`, but that doesn't return a locaiton

Comment: Also, do you know what `B == A` does/returns? If not, **then don't wrap it in two other functions and complain when you don't understand the results**.

Comment: The resulst have been included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for

```
B[which.max(A[B])]
## [1] 14
```

Which is the location of maximum `A` value within the indexes in `B`, which is

```
max(A[B])
## [1] 0.3348551
```

Comment: Thank you did not know which.max